# Filter json based on key and latest timestamp key in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a JSON file which is fetched from a remote api containing different app names and the timestamp along with other details. I need to filter this json with two filters i.e. App name + latest timestamp. The json file is as given below:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
          "appDetails": [
            {
              "appDescription": [
                {
                  "appName": "App 1",
                  "timeStamp": "2018-05-28T00:01:01.001Z",
                  "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.1.24",
                  "blocker": 3,
                  "critical": 4,
                  "major": 30,
                  "minor": 3,
                  "UnitTestsTotal": 59,
                  "FailedTests": 0,
                  "CodeCoverage": 90
                },
                {
                  "appName": "App 1",
                  "timeStamp": "2018-05-27T00:01:01.001Z",
                  "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.1.23",
                  "blocker": 3,
                  "critical": 4,
                  "major": 30,
                  "minor": 3,
                  "UnitTestsTotal": 59,
                  "FailedTests": 0,
                  "CodeCoverage": 90
                },
                {
                  "appName": "App 2",
                  "timeStamp": "2018-05-26T00:01:01.001Z",
                  "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.1.22",
                  "blocker": 3,
                  "critical": 4,
                  "major": 30,
                  "minor": 3,
                  "UnitTestsTotal": 59,
                  "FailedTests": 0,
                  "CodeCoverage": 90
                },
                {
                  "appName": "App 2",
                  "timeStamp": "2018-05-28T00:01:01.001Z",
                  "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.1.3",
                  "blocker": 3,
                  "critical": 4,
                  "major": 30,
                  "minor": 3,
                  "UnitTestsTotal": 59,
                  "FailedTests": 0,
                  "CodeCoverage": 90
                },
                {
                  "appName": "App 2",
                  "timeStamp": "2018-05-26T00:01:01.001Z",
                  "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.1.2",
                  "blocker": 3,
                  "critical": 4,
                  "major": 30,
                  "minor": 3,
                  "UnitTestsTotal": 59,
                  "FailedTests": 0,
                  "CodeCoverage": 90
                },
                {
                  "appName": "App 3",
                  "timeStamp": "2018-05-27T00:01:01.001Z",
                  "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.0.9",
                  "blocker": 3,
                  "critical": 4,
                  "major": 30,
                  "minor": 3,
                  "UnitTestsTotal": 59,
                  "FailedTests": 0,
                  "CodeCoverage": 90
                },
                {
                  "appName": "App 3",
                  "timeStamp": "2018-05-25T00:01:01.001Z",
                  "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.0.8",
                  "blocker": 3,
                  "critical": 4,
                  "major": 30,
                  "minor": 3,
                  "UnitTestsTotal": 59,
                  "FailedTests": 0,
                  "CodeCoverage": 90
                },
                {
                  "appName": "App 4",
                  "timeStamp": "2018-05-28T00:01:01.001Z",
                  "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.1.1.8",
                  "blocker": 3,
                  "critical": 4,
                  "major": 30,
                  "minor": 3,
                  "UnitTestsTotal": 59,
                  "FailedTests": 0,
                  "CodeCoverage": 90
                },
                {
                  "appName": "App 4",
                  "timeStamp": "2018-05-25T00:01:01.001Z",
                  "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.1.1.6",
                  "blocker": 3,
                  "critical": 4,
                  "major": 30,
                  "minor": 3,
                  "UnitTestsTotal": 59,
                  "FailedTests": 0,
                  "CodeCoverage": 90
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

For example, I would require a filtered array from the above json with both the app name and latest timestamp picked up.

```
filteredArray = [{
                  "appName": "App 1",
                  "timeStamp": "2018-05-28T00:01:01.001Z",
                  "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.1.24",
                  "blocker": 3,
                  "critical": 4,
                  "major": 30,
                  "minor": 3,
                  "UnitTestsTotal": 59,
                  "FailedTests": 0,
                  "CodeCoverage": 90
                  },
                  {
                  "appName": "App 2",
                  "timeStamp": "2018-05-28T00:01:01.001Z",
                  "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.1.3",
                  "blocker": 3,
                  "critical": 4,
                  "major": 30,
                  "minor": 3,
                  "UnitTestsTotal": 59,
                  "FailedTests": 0,
                  "CodeCoverage": 90
                },
                {
                  "appName": "App 3",
                  "timeStamp": "2018-05-27T00:01:01.001Z",
                  "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.0.9",
                  "blocker": 3,
                  "critical": 4,
                  "major": 30,
                  "minor": 3,
                  "UnitTestsTotal": 59,
                  "FailedTests": 0,
                  "CodeCoverage": 90
                },
                {
                  "appName": "App 4",
                  "timeStamp": "2018-05-28T00:01:01.001Z",
                  "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.1.1.8",
                  "blocker": 3,
                  "critical": 4,
                  "major": 30,
                  "minor": 3,
                  "UnitTestsTotal": 59,
                  "FailedTests": 0,
                  "CodeCoverage": 90
                }
]
```

My angularjs code present right now is as given below:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.tableData = [{
              "appName": "App 1",
              "timeStamp": "2018-05-28T00:01:01.001Z",
              "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.1.24",
              "blocker": 3,
              "critical": 4,
              "major": 30,
              "minor": 3,
              "UnitTestsTotal": 59,
              "FailedTests": 0,
              "CodeCoverage": 90
            },
            {
              "appName": "App 1",
              "timeStamp": "2018-05-27T00:01:01.001Z",
              "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.1.23",
              "blocker": 3,
              "critical": 4,
              "major": 30,
              "minor": 3,
              "UnitTestsTotal": 59,
              "FailedTests": 0,
              "CodeCoverage": 90
            },
            {
              "appName": "App 2",
              "timeStamp": "2018-05-26T00:01:01.001Z",
              "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.1.22",
              "blocker": 3,
              "critical": 4,
              "major": 30,
              "minor": 3,
              "UnitTestsTotal": 59,
              "FailedTests": 0,
              "CodeCoverage": 90
            },
            {
              "appName": "App 2",
              "timeStamp": "2018-05-28T00:01:01.001Z",
              "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.1.3",
              "blocker": 3,
              "critical": 4,
              "major": 30,
              "minor": 3,
              "UnitTestsTotal": 59,
              "FailedTests": 0,
              "CodeCoverage": 90
            },
            {
              "appName": "App 2",
              "timeStamp": "2018-05-26T00:01:01.001Z",
              "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.1.2",
              "blocker": 3,
              "critical": 4,
              "major": 30,
              "minor": 3,
              "UnitTestsTotal": 59,
              "FailedTests": 0,
              "CodeCoverage": 90
            },
            {
              "appName": "App 3",
              "timeStamp": "2018-05-27T00:01:01.001Z",
              "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.0.9",
              "blocker": 3,
              "critical": 4,
              "major": 30,
              "minor": 3,
              "UnitTestsTotal": 59,
              "FailedTests": 0,
              "CodeCoverage": 90
            },
            {
              "appName": "App 3",
              "timeStamp": "2018-05-25T00:01:01.001Z",
              "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.0.8",
              "blocker": 3,
              "critical": 4,
              "major": 30,
              "minor": 3,
              "UnitTestsTotal": 59,
              "FailedTests": 0,
              "CodeCoverage": 90
            },
            {
              "appName": "App 4",
              "timeStamp": "2018-05-28T00:01:01.001Z",
              "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.1.1.8",
              "blocker": 3,
              "critical": 4,
              "major": 30,
              "minor": 3,
              "UnitTestsTotal": 59,
              "FailedTests": 0,
              "CodeCoverage": 90
            },
            {
              "appName": "App 4",
              "timeStamp": "2018-05-25T00:01:01.001Z",
              "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.1.1.6",
              "blocker": 3,
              "critical": 4,
              "major": 30,
              "minor": 3,
              "UnitTestsTotal": 59,
              "FailedTests": 0,
              "CodeCoverage": 90
            }

  ]

  $scope.appNames = Array.from(new Set($scope.tableData.map(a => a.appName)));;

  $scope.expanding = {};
  for (index = 0; index < $scope.appNames.length; index++) {
    $scope.expanding[$scope.appNames[index]] = false;
  }

  $scope.swapExpanding = function(name) {
    $scope.expanding[name] = !$scope.expanding[name];
  }

}
```

Please help me as I am new to javascript as well as angular js. Any help to filter the array in my angularjs code based on appName key as well as latest timestamp would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `reduce` to group by name, with a test inside to compare timestamps:

```js
const appDescription=[{"appName":"App 1","timeStamp":"2018-05-28T00:01:01.001Z","GitTag":"RELEASE-1.0.1.24","blocker":3,"critical":4,"major":30,"minor":3,"UnitTestsTotal":59,"FailedTests":0,"CodeCoverage":90},{"appName":"App 1","timeStamp":"2018-05-27T00:01:01.001Z","GitTag":"RELEASE-1.0.1.23","blocker":3,"critical":4,"major":30,"minor":3,"UnitTestsTotal":59,"FailedTests":0,"CodeCoverage":90},{"appName":"App 2","timeStamp":"2018-05-26T00:01:01.001Z","GitTag":"RELEASE-1.0.1.22","blocker":3,"critical":4,"major":30,"minor":3,"UnitTestsTotal":59,"FailedTests":0,"CodeCoverage":90},{"appName":"App 2","timeStamp":"2018-05-28T00:01:01.001Z","GitTag":"RELEASE-1.0.1.3","blocker":3,"critical":4,"major":30,"minor":3,"UnitTestsTotal":59,"FailedTests":0,"CodeCoverage":90},{"appName":"App 2","timeStamp":"2018-05-26T00:01:01.001Z","GitTag":"RELEASE-1.0.1.2","blocker":3,"critical":4,"major":30,"minor":3,"UnitTestsTotal":59,"FailedTests":0,"CodeCoverage":90},{"appName":"App 3","timeStamp":"2018-05-27T00:01:01.001Z","GitTag":"RELEASE-1.0.0.9","blocker":3,"critical":4,"major":30,"minor":3,"UnitTestsTotal":59,"FailedTests":0,"CodeCoverage":90},{"appName":"App 3","timeStamp":"2018-05-25T00:01:01.001Z","GitTag":"RELEASE-1.0.0.8","blocker":3,"critical":4,"major":30,"minor":3,"UnitTestsTotal":59,"FailedTests":0,"CodeCoverage":90},{"appName":"App 4","timeStamp":"2018-05-28T00:01:01.001Z","GitTag":"RELEASE-1.1.1.8","blocker":3,"critical":4,"major":30,"minor":3,"UnitTestsTotal":59,"FailedTests":0,"CodeCoverage":90},{"appName":"App 4","timeStamp":"2018-05-25T00:01:01.001Z","GitTag":"RELEASE-1.1.1.6","blocker":3,"critical":4,"major":30,"minor":3,"UnitTestsTotal":59,"FailedTests":0,"CodeCoverage":90}];
const filteredAppsByName = appDescription.reduce((a, app) => {
  const { appName, timeStamp } = app;
  if (
    !a[appName]
    || (new Date(a[appName].timeStamp) < new Date(timeStamp))
  ) a[appName] = app;
  return a;
}, {});
const output = Object.values(filteredAppsByName);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

- Loop over items with `forEach`
- If data does not exists in array add it
- Else compare timestamps and if the condition satisfied, replace old data with new one

```js
var x = { "data": [{ "appDetails": [{ "appDescription": [{ "appName": "App 1", "timeStamp": "2018-05-28T00:01:01.001Z", "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.1.24", "blocker": 3, "critical": 4, "major": 30, "minor": 3, "UnitTestsTotal": 59, "FailedTests": 0, "CodeCoverage": 90 }, { "appName": "App 1", "timeStamp": "2018-05-27T00:01:01.001Z", "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.1.23", "blocker": 3, "critical": 4, "major": 30, "minor": 3, "UnitTestsTotal": 59, "FailedTests": 0, "CodeCoverage": 90 }, { "appName": "App 2", "timeStamp": "2018-05-26T00:01:01.001Z", "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.1.22", "blocker": 3, "critical": 4, "major": 30, "minor": 3, "UnitTestsTotal": 59, "FailedTests": 0, "CodeCoverage": 90 }, { "appName": "App 2", "timeStamp": "2018-05-28T00:01:01.001Z", "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.1.3", "blocker": 3, "critical": 4, "major": 30, "minor": 3, "UnitTestsTotal": 59, "FailedTests": 0, "CodeCoverage": 90 }, { "appName": "App 2", "timeStamp": "2018-05-26T00:01:01.001Z", "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.1.2", "blocker": 3, "critical": 4, "major": 30, "minor": 3, "UnitTestsTotal": 59, "FailedTests": 0, "CodeCoverage": 90 }, { "appName": "App 3", "timeStamp": "2018-05-27T00:01:01.001Z", "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.0.9", "blocker": 3, "critical": 4, "major": 30, "minor": 3, "UnitTestsTotal": 59, "FailedTests": 0, "CodeCoverage": 90 }, { "appName": "App 3", "timeStamp": "2018-05-25T00:01:01.001Z", "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.0.0.8", "blocker": 3, "critical": 4, "major": 30, "minor": 3, "UnitTestsTotal": 59, "FailedTests": 0, "CodeCoverage": 90 }, { "appName": "App 4", "timeStamp": "2018-05-28T00:01:01.001Z", "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.1.1.8", "blocker": 3, "critical": 4, "major": 30, "minor": 3, "UnitTestsTotal": 59, "FailedTests": 0, "CodeCoverage": 90 }, { "appName": "App 4", "timeStamp": "2018-05-25T00:01:01.001Z", "GitTag": "RELEASE-1.1.1.6", "blocker": 3, "critical": 4, "major": 30, "minor": 3, "UnitTestsTotal": 59, "FailedTests": 0, "CodeCoverage": 90 } ] }] }] };

var filtered_x = [];
x["data"][0]["appDetails"][0]["appDescription"].forEach(function(itm) {
  var index = filtered_x.findIndex(function(iitt) {
    return itm["appName"] == iitt["appName"];
  });
  if (index == -1) {
    filtered_x.push(itm);
  } else if(new Date(filtered_x[index]["timeStamp"]) < new Date(itm["timeStamp"])){
    filtered_x[index] = itm;
  }
});

console.log(filtered_x)
```